# Puppet agent on Debian client does not start on boot

Tags: puppet

I have a Debian VM with puppet client installed.
All is well when I manually run:
`puppet agent`

after I run it, I can see using "`service puppet status`" that the process is running OK.

I want this process (starting the puppet agent) to happen automatically on system boot.
I followed the instructions of changing /etc/init.d/puppet so that it starts

```
START=yes
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/puppet
DAEMON_OPTS=""
NAME=agent
DESC="puppet agent"
PIDFILE="/var/run/puppet/${NAME}.pid"
```

BUT - when I boot the system, this service does not start !

What am I doing wrong ?
I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `START=yes` in `/etc/default/puppet` instead of right in the initscript.

As an aside, this question would be more suitable on ServerFault.